# Java Runtime executes program with delay

Tags: java, python, swing, process

I have a `JButton` that has an overridden `actionPerformed(event)` function as the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("enters here");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python tetris.py");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the Python subprocess begins while Java program is being executed and hence the console for the subprocess, which is meant to display as a full screen, is shrunk to a smaller size. So I decided to terminate the Java program before executing its subsequent process:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("enters here");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python tetris.py");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

This presented a newer problem - although the subsequent process does appear as a full screen, because the Java program terminates before tetris.py gets fully executed, there is a delay between two processes, resulting the desktop content to blink for a second before tetris.py begins to run. At this point, I used `waitFor()`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("enters here");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python tetris.py");
        p.waitFor();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

As it turns out, `waitFor()` waits for the subprocess to terminate, which has the same problem from the first scenario in that the subprocess console is shrunk in size.

My goal is one of the following:

1. Either find a way for the subprocess to execute in full-screen mode (it does this on its own).
2. The parent process (Java program) can terminate if the subprocess executes correctly, but I need to get rid of the delay between the two processes.

I prefer the option of terminating the Java program because when I switch back from its subprocess to its own process with JPanel, the positions of all JButtons are messed up and hence requires a new execution anyways. Any inputs would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

What laune suggested didn't exactly work, as `ProcessBuilder` seemed to take effect as soon as the `JButton` is clicked, but I got an idea from there. Instead of checking the status of the subprocess, I just put the Java process to sleep for a certain duration (experimental value that lies somewhere between the points where Python program executing in a smaller window and Java program terminating too early to produce a prolonged delay).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "tetris.py");
        Process p = pb.start();
        Thread.sleep(300);          // less than 315 ~ 320 transition
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

No matter what value I used, however, I could not make the transition happen flawlessly and the desktop content blinks briefly but the delay is shorter than before. To counteract this even further, I was thinking of setting the desktop black to make it seem nothing was being shown, but this obviously is not an idle approach - it depends on the performance of the processor and hence has a poor portability, not to mention that this does not provide a real solution to the problem. Any further pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How about hiding your UI before launching Python?

Comment: You mean hide the UI of the Java program before executing its Python subprocess? Wouldn't it have the same effect as showing the desktop content? Do you mean I should black out the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "tetris.py" );
Process p = pb.start();
while( ! p.isAlive() ){
    Thread.sleep( 10 );
}
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I see the logic and I have tried it with longer duration of sleep as well, but it still presents the delay. I noticed that the Java JPanel gets minimized and the desktop content gets displayed the moment JButton is clicked. Think it might be doing this ProcessBuilder regardless of the status of the subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You want fullscreen, give it fullscreen with [setFullScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-). Try to avoid workarounds like the one you did. They almost always lead to other errors and workarounds which in the end make your app become unmaintainable.

I can't test it, but I hope it works for you.

Also, if you really have to do it your way, you shouldn't use System.exit(0) but instead [Platform.exit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--).